# Sync fork on GitHub

Tags: github, fork, pull-request

There are two repositories: the original and the fork. The original is a few commits ahead of the fork. The fork is a few commits ahead of the original. On the fork I see this:
[image]

I want to update the fork ONLY. I do not want any changes from the fork going into the original. Normally I would use the Sync fork option, but it does not work in this case.
[image]

How can I update the fork without updating the original using the GitHub interface?

I tried creating a pull request, but this updates both the fork and the original.
[image]